# After upgrading to iOS 5, I lost my all calendars, contacts, and message data

Tags: iphone, upgrade

Today I upgraded my iPhone 4 to the newest iOS. In the process steps it asked something like start from new iOS, or start from your back-up in iTunes, I selected the first one and then noticed there are no contacts, nor messages!

My iTunes had a problem and I thought I had backed up the files in my iTunes but I checked `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`

Comment: I think your last sentence got cut off somewhat. You checked the folder and found what?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you do:

1. Go to settings
2. Click on Mail, Contacts and Calendars
3. Scroll down and go to Calendars
4. Open the Sync screen
5. Check the box which says All Events
6. In about five minutes time, go back to your calendar which should have all of your previous events restored.

Happy days.

Answer (score 0):

Try a 'Restore' on your iPhone from iTunes and when it asks whether you'd like to start from a new iOS or backup, choose the backup.

(What was the 'problem' you had with iTunes?)

Comment: If `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` is empty as somewhat implied in the question, this will unfortunately not work.